# Can I make the dropdown visible after entering one character in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-select

I'm using **react-select** React component to display an autocomplete input field.

On focusing the react-select component input field, it will display all the **options** available which I don't want since the length of the data-set is in thousands. I want to display options only if the user enters at-least one character. Is there any way to do this? Or Is this a feature request that I'm supposed to raise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add `openOnClick={false}` Prop to the Select.

> open the options menu when the control is clicked (requires searchable = true)

Comment: Thanks, strange that this doesn't seem to be documented

Comment: `openOnClick` doesn't prevent to open select until minimum characters was entered, it just not open it until it's not focused

Comment: Now it's `openMenuOnClick={false}`

Comment: openMenuOnClick={false} works as expected for the first time, but after selecting the value from options, its blocking the input field as non-editable